# Investigation of optimal sleep time calculation in game loop

Tags: java, animation, game-engine

When programming animations and little games I've come to know the incredible importance of `Thread.sleep(n);` I rely on this method to tell the operating system when my application won't need any CPU, and using this making my program progress in a predictable speed.

My problem is that the JRE uses different methods of implementation of this functionality on different operating systems. On UNIX-based (or influenced) OS:es such as Ubuntu and OS X, the underlying JRE implementation uses a well-functioning and precise system for distributing CPU-time to different applications, and so making my 2D game smooth and lag-free. However, on Windows 7 and older Microsoft systems, the CPU-time distribution seems to work differently, and you usually get back your CPU-time after the given amount of sleep, varying with about 1-2 ms from target sleep. However, you get occasional bursts of extra 10-20 ms of sleep time. This causes my game to lag once every few seconds when this happens. I've noticed this problem exists on most Java games I've tried on Windows, Minecraft being a noticeable example.

Now, I've been looking around on the Internet to find a solution to this problem. I've seen a lot of people using only `Thread.yield();` instead of `Thread.sleep(n);`, which works flawlessly at the cost of the currently used CPU core getting full load, no matter how much CPU your game actually needs. This is not ideal for playing your game on laptops or high energy consumption workstations, and it's an unnecessary trade-off on Macs and Linux systems.

Looking around further I found a commonly used method of correcting sleep time inconsistencies called "spin-sleep", where you only order sleep for 1 ms at a time and check for consistency using the `System.nanoTime();` method, which is very accurate even on Microsoft systems. This helps for the normal 1-2 ms of sleep inconsistency, but it won't help against the occasional bursts of +10-20 ms of sleep inconsistency, since this often results in more time spent than one cycle of my loop should take all together.

After tons of looking I found this cryptic article of Andy Malakov, which was very helpful in improving my loop: http://andy-malakov.blogspot.com/2010/06/alternative-to-threadsleep.html

Based on his article I wrote this sleep method:

```
// Variables for calculating optimal sleep time. In nanoseconds (1s = 10^-9ms).
private long timeBefore = 0L;
private long timeSleepEnd, timeLeft;

// The estimated game update rate.
private double timeUpdateRate;

// The time one game loop cycle should take in order to reach the max FPS.
private long timeLoop;

private void sleep() throws InterruptedException {

    // Skip first game loop cycle.
    if (timeBefore != 0L) {

        // Calculate optimal game loop sleep time.
        timeLeft = timeLoop - (System.nanoTime() - timeBefore);

        // If all necessary calculations took LESS time than given by the sleepTimeBuffer. Max update rate was reached.
        if (timeLeft > 0 && isUpdateRateLimited) {

            // Determine when to stop sleeping.
            timeSleepEnd = System.nanoTime() + timeLeft;

            // Sleep, yield or keep the thread busy until there is not time left to sleep.
            do {
                if (timeLeft > SLEEP_PRECISION) {
                    Thread.sleep(1); // Sleep for approximately 1 millisecond.
                }
                else if (timeLeft > SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION) {
                    Thread.yield(); // Yield the thread.
                }
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    throw new InterruptedException();
            }
                timeLeft = timeSleepEnd - System.nanoTime();
            }
            while (timeLeft > 0);
        }
        // Save the calculated update rate.
        timeUpdateRate =  1000000000D / (double) (System.nanoTime() - timeBefore);
    }
    // Starting point for time measurement.
    timeBefore = System.nanoTime();
}
```

`SLEEP_PRECISION` I usually put to about 2 ms, and `SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION` to about 10 000 ns for best performance on my Windows 7 machine.

After tons of hard work, this is the absolute best I can come up with. So, since I still care about improving the accuracy of this sleep method, and I'm still not satisfied with the performance, I would like to appeal to all of you java game hackers and animators out there for suggestions on a better solution for the Windows platform. Could I use a platform-specific way on Windows to make it better? I don't care about having a little platform specific code in my applications, as long as the majority of the code is OS independent.

I would also like to know if there is anyone who knows about Microsoft and Oracle working out a better implementation of the `Thread.sleep(n);` method, or what's Oracle's future plans are on improving their environment as the basis of applications requiring high timing accuracy, such as music software and games?

Thank you all for reading my lengthy question/article. I hope some people might find my research helpful!

Comment: Hvae you tried adding scheduled tasks to a ScheduleExecutorService. This allow you to perform task ever 1 ms or pretty close to it.

Comment: Are you sure the `10-20 ms of sleep time` is what is causing the lag? Even at 50FPS that is only a single frame that is being dropped or delayed until his successor. Maybe it is the formula by which you calculate the positions of your sprites instead.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - actually, in some situations ScheduledExecutorService may perform worse since it uses the nano times api.  we've encountered situations where the nano times stuff was completely unreliable on windows (primarily when running as a virtual guest).

Comment: @eznme No, I'm not actually dead sure. I've tried my best to run different benchmarks and try to pin down the problem, but I haven't been able to figure out a whole lot. According to Barfieldmv's reply the lag might actually be worse than I thought. Currently I'm actually only drawing filled rectangles, so I don't think I have any problem with my sprite algorithm, since there is none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a  [cyclic timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) associated with a [mutex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). This is IHMO the most efficient way of doing what you want. But then you should think about skipping frames in case the computer lags (You can do it with another nonblocking mutex in the timer code.)

Edit: Some pseudo-code to clarify

Timer code:

```
While(true):
  if acquireIfPossible(mutexSkipRender):
    release(mutexSkipRender)
    release(mutexRender)
```

Sleep code:

```
acquire(mutexSkipRender)
acquire(mutexRender)
release(mutexSkipRender)
```

Starting values:

```
mutexSkipRender = 1
mutexRender = 0
```

**Edit**: corrected initialization values.

The following code work pretty well on windows (loops at exactly 50fps with a precision to the millisecond)

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Semaphore mutexRefresh = new Semaphore(0);
        final Semaphore mutexRefreshing = new Semaphore(1);
        int refresh = 0;

        Timer timRefresh = new Timer();
        timRefresh.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mutexRefreshing.tryAcquire()) {
                    mutexRefreshing.release();
                    mutexRefresh.release();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000/50);

        // The timer is started and configured for 50fps
        Date startDate = new Date();
        while(true) { // Refreshing loop
            mutexRefresh.acquire();
            mutexRefreshing.acquire();

            // Refresh 
            refresh += 1;

            if(refresh % 50 == 0) {
                Date endDate = new Date();
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(50.0*1000/(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())) + " fps.");
                startDate = new Date();
            }

            mutexRefreshing.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really interesting. I'll look into this and try out some code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wasn't able to get any good results at all with a simplification of your approach. Would you be able to link to an article or something which shows how this could be implemented in a game or animation situation? Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit about the simplification and problems you encountered ? I guess the use of java's Semaphore could induce some performances-related problems for a game, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion in a little demo program I made with tons of squares flying around the screen. The main code I used was this: `animationTimer.schedule(new GameLoop(), 0, 12);` I know this isn't quite all of the stuff you asked me to do, but it shouldn't be a problem as long as my computer is very fast and the program takes very little time to execute (each game loop cycle takes less than 1 ms so the loop will never take more time than 12 ms). I got the same lag bursts here as I got with my own code. Maybe the scheduler is implemented using `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: See my code in the edited response, and I don't know how Timer is implemented in java, try this code and tell me if it works without bursts. In my machine, it does.

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! I'm not sure why though! I'll take a look into the mechanics later on. I tried to put your code into my little test app with moving squares. Your code caused my program to take less than half the CPU compared to my old code. I still got some wierd behaviour in my animation though, but not very frequently, and I suspect it migh have been the window-managers fault, or something else unrelated to the precision of your code. I'll take my time optimizing and integrating it to my game later on. Thanks's again for your time!

Comment: Timer are generally implemented using software or even hardware interrupts, they are the faster and simplier approach to synchronisation problems. I don't know how they are implemented in java, though, but I guess they are using the [win32 Timer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741307(v=vs.85).aspx) that is made exactly for this kind of problems.

Comment: A friend of mine helped me out to find the source code for the Semaphore class in the OpenJDK. It can be found here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/file/e251bf6cbfb4/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.java It doesn't use sleep() at all, which is nice to see! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Your options are limited, and they depend on what exactly you want to do. Your code snippet mentions the max FPS, but the max FPS would require that you never sleep at all, so I'm not entirely sure what you intend with that. None of that sleep or yield checking is going to make any difference in most of the problem situations however - if some other app needs to run now and the OS doesn't want to switch back soon, it doesn't matter which one of those you call, you'll get control back when the OS decides to do so, which will almost certainly be more than 1ms in the future. However, the OS can certainly be coaxed into making switches more often - Win32 has the [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call for precisely this purpose, which you may be able to use somehow. But there is a good reason for not switching too often - it's less efficient.

The best thing to do, although somewhat more complex, is usually to go for a game loop that doesn't require real-time updates, but instead performs logic updates at fixed intervals (eg. 20x a second) and renders whenever possible (perhaps with arbitrary short sleeps to free up CPU for other apps, if not running in full-screen). By buffering a past logic state as well as the current one you can interpolate between them to make the rendering appear as smooth as if you were doing logic updates each time. For more information on this approach, you can see the [Fix Your Timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) article.

> I would also like to know if there is anyone who knows about Microsoft and Oracle working out a better implementation of the Thread.sleep(n); method, or what's Oracle's future plans are on improving their environment as the basis of applications requiring high timing accuracy, such as music software and games?

No, this won't be happening. Remember, sleep is just a method saying how long you want your program to be asleep for. It is not a specification for when it will or should wake up, and never will be. By definition, any system with sleep and yield functionality is a multitasking system, where the requirements of other tasks have to be considered, and the operating system always gets the final call on the scheduling of this. The alternative wouldn't work reliably, because if a program could somehow demand to be reactivated at a precise time of its choosing it could starve other processes of CPU power. (eg. A program that spawned a background thread and had both threads performing 1ms of work and calling sleep(1) at the end could take turns to hog a CPU core.) Thus, for a user-space program, sleep (and functionality like it) will always be a lower bound, never an upper bound. To do better than that requires the OS itself to allow certain apps to pretty much own the scheduling, and this is not a desirable feature in operating systems for consumer hardware (while being a common and useful feature for industrial applications).

Comment: Well, my comments may not be completely explicit. With reaching max FPS I mean that the desired frame rate was achieved. `timeLoop` (the time one cycle of the loop should take) is calculated by dividing one second with the desired FPS (usually 60).

Answer (score 2):

Thread.Sleep says you're app needs no more time. This means that in a worst case scenario you'll have to wait for an entire thread slice (40ms or so).

Now in bad cases when a driver or something takes up more time it could be you have to wait for 120ms (3*40ms) so Thread.Sleep is not the way to go. Go another way, like registering a 1ms callback and starting draw code very X callbacks.

(This is on windows, i'd use MultiMedia tools to get those 1ms resolution callbacks)

Comment: I'll look into this! Thank you for the suggestion. I'll keep the question open till I've read around about it and some more people answered the question!

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to figure out anything about MultiMedia tools. Could you link to a reference or anything that could help me get it sorted out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Timing stuff is notoriously bad on windows.  [This article](http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) is a good place to start.  Not sure if you care, but also note that there can be worse problems (especially with System.nanoTime) on virtual systems as well (when windows is the guest operating system).

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` is inaccurate and makes the animation jittery most of the time.

If you replace it completely with `Thread.yield` you'll get a solid FPS without lag or jitter, however the CPU usage increases greatly. I moved to Thread.yield a long time ago.

This problem has been discussed on Java Game Development forums for years.

Comment: Please don't reply late to 3 month old posts with basically the same information as is already in the thread! Or at least make it a comment.