# Android game loop timing discrepancy

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-loop

I have been working on my first game ever :)

It is a android based game using libgdx and is using a modified example of one the [DeWiTTERS loop](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/)

The game loop seems to work perfectly fine running on the desktop (59 - 60 fps) however when i run on my phone it tends to sit somewhere around 75 - 90 FPS

nextGameTick should always be referingto 16ms into the future so that the game loop runs at 60 FPS or less, why is this not the case

Here is the main part of the game loop for reference:

```
public void render() {
    nextGameTick = System.nanoTime() + skipTicks;
    loopTimeFull = System.nanoTime();

    Application app = Gdx.app;

    screen.update(app); // Update the screen
    screen.render(app); // Render the screen

    // when the screen is done we change to the
    // next screen
    if (screen.isDone()) {
        // dispose the current screen
        screen.dispose();
        <snip>
        // Removed unneded part of code for this example
        </snip>
        }
    }

    // Make the thread sleep
    General.renderTime = System.nanoTime() - loopTimeFull;
    while (System.nanoTime() <= nextGameTick - General.renderTime) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    General.loopTime = System.nanoTime() - loopTimeFull;
    if (General.loopTime > 0)
        General.curFps = 1000000000 / General.loopTime;
    else
        Gdx.app.log("Air Offense", "General.loopTime == 0");
```

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of `General.curFps = 1000000000 / General.loopTime;`?

Comment: @MisterSmith thats what calculates the FPS

it divides the number of nanoseconds in a second by the time the loop took in nanoseconds

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but it seems to me bad design to sleep for that small ammount of time. It is roughly an active wait. The `Thread.sleep` method you are using has a parameter in ms. There's an overloaded method accepting ns also. However, neither of these are guaranteed to sleep exactly a certain ammount of time. To have a greater precission, use a Timer to sleep exactly the required ns in a single wait.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274619/investigation-of-optimal-sleep-time-calculation-in-game-loop

Comment: @MisterSmith I have implemented the code in the the link from your last comment to great success thank you. regarding the comment previous to that one, I had a look at using timers a week or so ago but i couldn't find a way to implement it in libgdx as the render() method loops continuously. also how do i give you a great comment vote? :p

Comment: Thanks! If you wish, you can answer your question with your solution and mark it as solved, so that other people can learn from it too. It is a very interesting question.

Comment: @MisterSmith i cant mark it as solved because you havn't answered the question yet ;P

Comment: Answer it yourself! I have not much time now XD. And you could put a link to that other question about the Timer, in the comments it hasn't enough visibility.